# Simulate control+key event

Tags: vb.net

From time to time I use code to simulate key event.
Like this:

```
Dim kea As New KeyEventArgs(Keys.N)
DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender, kea)
```

That work's good.
Now I need same way to send Ctrl+N.
But I can't find how to do this.

What I try...

```
Dim kea As New KeyEventArgs(Keys.N And Keys.ControlKey)
```

But that don't want to work as expected.

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you could have read in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keyeventargs.aspx), you should combine the keys with the bitwise OR operator:

```
Dim kea As New KeyEventArgs(Keys.N Or Keys.Control)
```

Comment: But that unfortunately don't pass "If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.N Then" under DataGridView1 KeyDown event handler.

Comment: OK, that work's. KeyEventArgs(Keys.N Or Keys.Control) Thank you.

Comment: C sharp version: new KeyEventArgs(Keys.N | Keys.Control)